# Jmeter_Passing differnet account numbers from parameters file in single request

Tags: random, parameters, jmeter

How to pass several values in a single request, if I have 20 account numbers, we must pass 5 distinct numbers each time in single iteration, For EX my script (single request) has 5 calls and we need to pass 5 different account numbers each time from single request (post method),

Accnum:-
2123
5678
9890
6780
8899
9990
7651
8976
Example:-

call 1: - 2123
call 2: - 9890
call 3: - 5678 so on...

I tried adding 5 csv files, but it will be time consuming, so I wanted to use formula.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single CSV file and:

- either [__CSVRead()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) function where you decide when to proceed to the next line
- or [__StringFromFile()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) function which reads the next line each time when it's being called
- or [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) if your "formula" is more complex

If you need more comprehensive instructions use proper [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to show how does you file look like and specify how the values from it will be used in the request

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions)